# Grey Screen on boot from GPU on PC

Tags: drivers, gpu, amd-radeon

New to Manjaro, previously have only used Debian-based distros so sorry if Im missing something obvious. I have an AMD rx 560 that was tested and working before I bought it but whenever I try to use it, grey screens.

Even after installing the recommended open-source drivers and proprietary drivers it still doesn’t work. I updated and downloaded all of the necessary firmware and then some. Still nothing.

And it doesn’t matter if I use the display port or the HDMI port, I still get a grey screen with a green outline for a few seconds then no signal. Is this a driver issue or a hardware issue?

Comment: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/cant-enter-grub-menu-esc-shows-grey-screen/132226/11

Comment: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/stuck-on-grey-login-screen-after-boot/113293/3

Comment: If you google "manjaro grey screen" you get a bunch of results